# Executing file on windows from linux server

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell, shell, execution

Is it possible to execute files(.exe, .py, .bat etc.) on windows server from linux server. The files are stored in Linux machine. if it is possible then how we can achieve it by making python or shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use paramiko to create a ssh connection to the remote Linux server, download the executable and run it. I had some python code lying around that should work great for you:

```py
import os

import paramiko


def create_ssh_connection(username, hostname, port=22, rsa_key=None, password=None):
    if rsa_key:
        rsa_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(rsa_key, password=password)
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    ssh.connect(
        hostname=hostname,
        username=username,
        pkey=rsa_key,
        password=password,
        port=port
    )

    return ssh


def main():
    # Create SSH connection
    ssh = create_ssh_connection("username", "hostname", password="password")
    # Create SFTP connection
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

    # Get file from remote server
    remote_path = "/home/username/example.py"
    local_path = "example.py"
    sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)

    # Execute file
    os.system(local_path)


    # Delete file, if you only want to run it once
    os.remove(local_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thanks but i want to execute files from linux to windows.

Comment: So your file is located on a Linux server, you want to connect with a Windows server and execute the file on the Windows server?